# Solving complicated non-linear equation in python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-equation

I have got two non - linear equations with two variables a and b. I am trying to solve it using fsolve but it is showing error.

Can someone suggest if these equations can be solved or not
It involves logarithm which I got using sympy.log()

Equation 1:

```
-a*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*a) - a*(48973.016*a - 23402.7518) + b*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*b) + b*(48973.016*b - 23402.7518) + (1 - a)*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*a) + (1 - a)*(48973.016*a - 23402.7518) - (1 - b)*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*b) - (1 - b)*(48973.016*b - 23402.7518) + 4731.31823640719 - (b/(1 - b))**(-9600*b)*((b/(1 - b))**(9600*b)*(1 - b)**9600*(9600*(1 - b)*(b/(1 - b)**2 + 1/(1 - b)) + 9600*log(b/(1 - b))) - 9600*(b/(1 - b))**(9600*b)*(1 - b)**9599)/(1 - b)**9600 + (a/(1 - a))**(-9600*a)*((a/(1 - a))**(9600*a)*(1 - a)**9600*(9600*(1 - a)*(a/(1 - a)**2 + 1/(1 - a)) + 9600*log(a/(1 - a))) - 9600*(a/(1 - a))**(9600*a)*(1 - a)**9599)/(1 - a)**9600
```

Equation2:

```
-a*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*a) - a*(48973.016*a - 23402.7518) + (1 - a)*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*a) + (1 - a)*(48973.016*a - 23402.7518) + 10382.138477723 - (a*(1 - a)*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*a) + a*(1 - a)*(48973.016*a - 23402.7518) + 10382.138477723*a - b*(1 - b)*(25570.2642 - 48973.016*b) - b*(1 - b)*(48973.016*b - 23402.7518) - 5650.82024131583*b + log((a/(1 - a))**(9600*a)*(1 - a)**9600) - log((b/(1 - b))**(9600*b)*(1 - b)**9600) + 320.132207782401)/(a - b) + (a/(1 - a))**(-9600*a)*((a/(1 - a))**(9600*a)*(1 - a)**9600*(9600*(1 - a)*(a/(1 - a)**2 + 1/(1 - a)) + 9600*log(a/(1 - a))) - 9600*(a/(1 - a))**(9600*a)*(1 - a)**9599)/(1 - a)**9600
```

Code

```
def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (eq1, eq2)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in __float__(self)
    348         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    349             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 350         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
    351 
    352     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-1d80da78acbb> in <module>()
     91     return (eq1, eq2)
     92 
---> 93 x, y =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    223             maxfev = 200 * (n + 1)
    224         retval = _minpack._hybrd(func, x0, args, 1, xtol, maxfev,
--> 225                                  ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    226     else:
    227         _check_func('fsolve', 'fprime', Dfun, x0, args, n, (n, n))

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: Is this `fsolve` from `sympy` or `scipy`?  You can't use `sympy` expressions in numeric solvers, since the expressions don't convert to floats.  Isn't obvious that's what the error is complaining about?

Comment: Since you have symbolic equations you should use SymPy's `nsolve` function rather than SciPy's `fsolve`.